# Alowing only Int's into QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating a gui on python, where person can enter some data into  several QPlainTextEdit elements. I want to check, is data Integer or not? If not- I need to delete all what was entered. I tried to do it via this:

```
 regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')
self.Start_i.textChanged.connect(QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp))
```

Where `Start_i` is one of the QPlainTextEdit elements, and in my mind it should check, is input data an integer from 0 to 255. But it's not working.
Seems like I need to use something like that:

```
if not self.Start_i.textChanged.connect(QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp))
self.Start_i.setPlainText(old_text[:-1])
```

but I stil dont know how to do it properly.

Also I know that there is QIntValidator(),tried it like this:

```
 self.Start_i.textChanged.connect(QtGui.QIntValidator(0,65535))
```

or

```
validator = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 100); 
self.Start_i.setValidator(validator)
```

UPD: I did this -

```
self.Start_i.textChanged.connect(validation)
```

and then:

```
def validation():
    regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')
    valid=QtGui.QRegExpValidator.validate(regexp)
    if not valid:
        Ui_IPG_weld.Start_i.setPlainText('0')
```

But got error:

```
TypeError: validate(self, str, int): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QRegExpValidator'
```

UPD 2: There is my full code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import re
import Ipg_weld
from Ipg_weld import Ui_IPG_weld
import Reading
import Writing


class Test(Ui_IPG_weld):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QMainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self.widget)
        # ...
        self.Read_Button.clicked.connect(self.read_file)
        self.Savebutton.clicked.connect(self.write_file)
        #validator = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 100); #Valid for values between 0 and 100
        #self.Start_i.setValidator(validator)
        self.Start_i.textChanged.connect(validation)
        self.widget.show()


    def read_file(self):
        file_values = Reading.reading()
        print("Got values from Setup_weld.src and Execute_weld.src:", file_values)
        # changing values in plainTexts
        self.Start_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][0])  #Start
        self.Strobe_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][1])  #Strobe
        self.Bit0_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][10])  #Bit0
        self.Bit1_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][9])  #Bit1
        self.Bit2_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][8])  #Bit2
        self.Bit3_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][7])  #Bit3
        self.Bit4_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][6])  #Bit4
        self.Bit5_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][5])  #Bit5
        self.Bit6_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][4])  #Bit6
        self.Bit7_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][3])  #Bit7
        self.Bit8_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][2])  #Bit8
        self.Enable_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][11])  #Enable
        self.Active_o.setPlainText(file_values[1][3]) #active
        self.Ready_o.setPlainText(file_values[1][0]) #ready
        self.Error_o.setPlainText(file_values[0][11]) #error

    def write_file(self):
       #new_values=Writing.writing()
       user_input=[]
       user_input.clear()
       user_input.append(self.Active_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Ready_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Error_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit0_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit1_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit2_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit3_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit4_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit5_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit6_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit7_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Bit8_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Strobe_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Start_i.toPlainText())
       user_input.append(self.Enable_i.toPlainText())
       print(user_input)


def validation():
    #regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')
    regexp = re.match('^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')
    valid=QtGui.QRegExpValidator.validate(regexp)
    if not valid:
     Ui_IPG_weld.Start_i.setPlainText('0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   main = Test()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have proposed a generic solution, I have doubts that is what you want, you could explain me better with examples of desired inputs and outputs. I ask this since the user usually writes letter by letter or paste it, in the second it is easy to solve but in the first it is difficult since you would have to know at what time the writing of the text begins. In the case of QLineEdit there are no problems because all the text is verified, but in your case it could not be done directly, unless it is line by line.

Comment: I added full code to make it more clear. I tried to adjust your code for my program, but that didn't work

Comment: My solution is not direct, but I need you to explain that you explain what kind of inputs you have and what kind of outputs you want to get with examples. I also need to show the Ui_IPG_weld code.

Comment: Because when validating a QLineEdit the entire text is validated and if the text is not valid, this text is not changed, but in the case of QPlainTextEdit the entire text must not be validated, but some strings, such as string separated by spaces : "123 545"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first solution is to implement the keyPressEvent method of QPlainText as shown below:

```
class PlainTextEdit(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')
        self.validator= QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        state = self.validator.validate(event.text(), 0)
        if state[0] == QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable:
            QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

But the disadvantage of this solution is that it will only serve when the user enters the text through the keyboard, but will not serve when it sticks some text.

Therefore it implements this new method that corrects this error:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PlainTextEdit(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')
        self.validator= QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp)
        self.document().contentsChange.connect(self.onContentsChange)

    def onContentsChange(self, position, charsRemoved, charsAdded):
        if charsAdded > 0:
            beforeText = self.toPlainText()[:position]
            text = self.toPlainText()[position:position+charsAdded]
            afterText = self.toPlainText()[position+charsAdded:]

            newText = ""

            for letter in text:
                state, _, _ = self.validator.validate(letter, 0)
                if state == QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable:
                    newText += letter

            oldState = self.document().blockSignals(True)
            self.setPlainText(beforeText+newText+afterText)
            self.document().blockSignals(oldState)

            cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.document())
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

If you want to use this class in Qt Designer you must promote it for this you must follow the following steps:

1. The structure of the project that I think you should have is the following:

---

```
.
├── Ipg_weld.py
├── main.py <----Main file that you show in your question.
└── your_designer.ui
```

2. You must create a new .py file and place in it the PlainTextEdit class that I am proposing, so the structure would look like this:

---

```
.
├── Ipg_weld.py
├── main.py <----Main file that you show in your question.
├── PlainTextEdit.py  <-- This file has the PlainTextEdit class.
└── your_designer.ui
```

3. Open the .ui file with the help of Qt Designer and click on the QPlainTextEdit button you want to put the validator, and choose the option **Promote to ...**:

[image]

4. You will get a dialog window as shown in the following image, in the box of Promoted class name you must put PlainTextEdit and in Header File you must place PlainTextEdit.h, after pressing add and Promote:

[image]

5. After converting the file ui again to the file Ipg_weld.py with the help of pyuic.

With the above the PlainTextEdit class will be loaded, you just need to run your main file.

Comment: Tried it. Looks like that worked but now when I'm trying to write anythong into self.Enable_o.setObjectName("Enable_o")
        self.Enable_i = PlainTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.Enable_i.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 520, 41, 31))
        self.Enable_i.setReadOnly(False)
        self.Enable_i.setPlainText("") it just frozing whole program

Comment: in other words - all PlainTextEdit elements working fine,but one of them making whole program freeze

Comment: Don't know what happened, but seems like it disappeared! Don't even know what happened, but thank you kindly, sir, for your patience and your time! Your solution worked perfect!